# Connecting Mysql with IntelliJ ultimate 2016.2.3 using JSP

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, jdbc, intellij-idea

Am new in JSP and the IntelliJ IDE am experiencing an error `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` when i try to login inside my Application. Am using IntelliJ as my IDE while developing a JSP project.  **How can I connect Mysql to a JSP project?**

Below is **LoginDao.java** class

```
package com.huza.schooldynamic;

/**
 * Created by HUZY_KAMZ on 9/8/2016.
 */
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class LoginDao {
    public static boolean validate(String name, String pass) {
        boolean status = false;
        Connection conn = null;
        PreparedStatement pst = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;

        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306";
        String dbName = "form";
        String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
        String userName = "root";
        String password = "namungoona";
        try {
            Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
            conn = DriverManager
                    .getConnection(url + dbName, userName, password);

            pst = conn

                .prepareStatement("select * from login where user=? and password=?");
        pst.setString(1, name);
        pst.setString(2, pass);

        rs = pst.executeQuery();
        status = rs.next();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    } finally {
        if (conn != null) {
            try {
                conn.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if (pst != null) {
            try {
                pst.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if (rs != null) {
            try {
                rs.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    return status;
}
```

}

and this is my servlet class **LoginServlet.java**

```
package com.huza.schooldynamic;

/**
 * Created by HUZY_KAMZ on 9/8/2016.
 */
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        String n=request.getParameter("username");
        String p=request.getParameter("userpass");

        HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
        if(session!=null)
            session.setAttribute("name", n);

        if(LoginDao.validate(n, p)){
            RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("welcome.jsp");
            rd.forward(request,response);
        }
        else{
            out.print("<p style=\"color:red\">Sorry username or password error</p>");
            RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp");
            rd.include(request,response);
        }

        out.close();
    }
}
```

This is my **index.jsp** file

```
<%--
  Created by IntelliJ IDEA.
  User: HUZY_KAMZ
  Date: 9/8/2016
  Time: 5:31 PM
  To change this template use File | Settings | File Templates.
--%>
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>School Management System</title>
  </head>
  <body>

  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <center>
  <form action="loginServlet" method="post">
    <fieldset style="width: 300px">
      <legend> Login here </legend>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>User ID</td>
          <td><input type="text" name="username" required="required" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Password</td>
          <td><input type="password" name="userpass" required="required" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input type="submit" value="Login" /></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </fieldset>
  </form>

  </center>


  </body>
</html>
```

This is my **welcome.jsp** file

```
<%--
  Created by IntelliJ IDEA.
  User: HUZY_KAMZ
  Date: 9/8/2016
  Time: 6:00 PM
  To change this template use File | Settings | File Templates.
--%>
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Welcome <%=session.getAttribute("name")%></title>
</head>
<body>
<h3>Login successful!!!</h3>
<h4>
    Hello,
    <%=session.getAttribute("name")%></h4>
</body>
</html>
```

And finally this is my **web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>login</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.huza.schooldynamic.LoginServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>login</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/loginServlet</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

So currently i have tried to view Mysql in the IntelliJ IDE but it seems i don't know how to connect it to the project , when i run the app and i try ti login this error comes in the IDE `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`.

Below is the picture of the IDE

[image: So in that picture , i view the database and the table , but how can i connect it to the project]

Comment: @Jozef Chocholacek , before you say its a duplicate please , am uisng  an  **IntelliJ IDE** not **Eclipse**, so my problem is about connectivity. So do you mean they are the same steps

Comment: Before you ask, learn some basics, and google for `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException com.mysql.jdbc.Driver web application` - your problem has **nothing** to do with what IDE you use.

Comment: @huxaiphaerIdris I use IntelliJ. You could try and add Maven to your project (right-click on module and select "Add framework"...and choose Maven). Then add your mysql dependency with Maven, that will get the dependency you need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `ClassNotFoundException` is telling you that it cannot find the class `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` on your classpath. In other words, non of the library JARs you have defined in your project contain that class.

That particular class is a MySQL specific implementations of the `java.sql.Driver` interface. (If you do not understand what an interface is, you can start wit the [Java tutorial's page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html) on it. But you'll want to do more learning about it since interfaces are a core concept of OOP).

Your DAO class says to use this particular diver in the line `String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";`. But when the code is running, it is not finding a class by that name. So you need to add that class to your classpath. By going to [Advance Search Page](http://search.maven.org/#advancedsearch%7Cgav) at the Maven Central, you can search for that (or any other) class to determine what libraries have it. In this particular case, it is in the `mysql-connector-java` JAR; the latest version of which is v6.0.4.

So yo need to add the `mysql-connector-java` JAR to your classpath , that is add it as a library to your Java project. How you do that depends on how you have set up your project.

If you are using Maven, you can add the required dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.4</version>
</dependency>
```

If you are using Gradle, add

```
compile 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:6.0.4'
```

If you are using Ant with Ivy, add

```
<dependency org="mysql" name="mysql-connector-java" rev="6.0.4" />
```

All those declarations I copied from the [information page](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Cmysql%7Cmysql-connector-java%7C6.0.4%7Cjar) for that JAR file at maven central.

If you are not using one of the above build tools, you will need to add the JAR to your project in another way. For example, if you are just using the Project configuration in IDEA, go to Project Structure (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> / <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>;</kbd>) and add it a new library to the module. See the [Library](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/library.html) IntelliJ IDEA help page and the pages it references for more information.

Comment: Thansk so much @Javaru , your answer has worked